# How to check a page has been completely downloaded?

Tags: c#, performance, download, webclient

We are using an application and recently there have been identified performance issues occurring occasionally - sometimes it takes over 3 minutes to download the front page. When all is OK, it takes couple of seconds only. I checked in the Chrome develper tools and I can see, that within those first 3 minutes that there are multiple "pings" sent to the server but the page remains blank. I'm trying to figure out, how to regularly check, if a web page has been completely downloaded.

Is there a way, how to check, that the front page has been completely downloaded ?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Why don't you analyze why your server is so slow _on the server_? Add monitoring, metrics, perhaps turn on debug logs or use a profiler (or load testing tools). Then start fixing those things.

Comment: The server belongs to an external vendor and I've very limited tracking possibilities. I can however run MS Visual Studio and create new scripts / apps. so I was thinking of creating something simple, that can run at the background and ping the server once an hour. I can then reuse the same script for other apps I'm supporting as well.